# how to sum conditional functions to grouped rows in R

Tags: r

I so have the following data frame

| customerid | payment_month | payment_date | bill_month | charges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 22 | January | 30 |
| 1 | February | 15 | February | 21 |
| 1 | March | 2 | March | 33 |
| 1 | May | 4 | April | 43 |
| 1 | May | 4 | May | 23 |
| 1 | June | 13 | June | 32 |
| 2 | January | 12 | January | 45 |
| 2 | February | 15 | February | 56 |
| 2 | March | 2 | March | 67 |
| 2 | April | 4 | April | 65 |
| 2 | May | 4 | May | 54 |
| 2 | June | 13 | June | 68 |
| 3 | January | 25 | January | 45 |
| 3 | February | 26 | February | 56 |
| 3 | March | 30 | March | 67 |
| 3 | April | 1 | April | 65 |
| 3 | June | 1 | May | 54 |
| 3 | June | 1 | June | 68 |

(the id data is much larger) I want to calculate payment efficiency using the following function,

efficiency = (amount paid not late / total bill amount)*100

not late is paying no later than the 21st day of the bill's month. (paying January's bill on the 22nd of January is considered as late)

I want to calculate the efficiency of each customer with the expected output of

| customerid | effectivity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 59.90 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 37.46 |

I have tried using the following code to calculate for one id and it works. but I want to apply and assign it to the entire group id and summarize it into 1 column (effectivity) and 1 row per ID. I have tried using group by, aggregate and ifelse functions but nothing works. What should I do?

```
df1 <- filter(df, (payment_month!=bill_month & id==1) | (payment_month==bill_month & payment_date > 21 & id==1) )
df2 <-filter(df, id==1001)
x <- sum(df1$charges)
x <- sum(df2$charges)
100-(x/y)*100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(customerid) %>%
    summarise(
        effectivity = sum(
            charges[payment_date <= 21 & payment_month == bill_month]) / sum(charges) * 100,
        .groups = "drop")
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#customerid effectivity
#       <int>       <dbl>
#1          1        59.9
#2          2       100  
#3          3        37.5
```

Comment: thanks! it worked. I changed the condition to payment_data >= 21 & payment_mont!=bill_month and subtract the effectivity with 100 to get the desired number and make it more precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(customerid) %>% 
  mutate(totalperid = sum(charges)) %>% 
  mutate(pay_month_number = match(payment_month , month.name),
         bill_month_number = match(bill_month , month.name)) %>% 
  mutate(nolate = ifelse(pay_month_number > bill_month_number, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  summarise(efficiency = case_when(nolate = TRUE ~ (charges/totalperid)*100))
```